# Cross platform 2D graphics/game library

Tags: image, 2d, game-engine

I'm looking for suggestions for a 2d game engine or library. I'm not picky about the language used but more about the capabilities of the library and the platforms it works on.

I would like to write one code base that would work on iOS, OSX, Android, Win and *nix. I understand there would be some platform specific code but I would like the bulk to be useable on all platforms.

I have looked around and I have some ideas but I'm looking for other opinions. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SDL(Simple DirectMedia Layer) http://www.libsdl.org/

Comment: I was thinking about this one. They have support for, or are working on support for, most of the platforms I mentioned. Its just very low level.

Comment: I haven't known it for long, but i am now trying to make a game on win and osx with SDL. The installation and initialization are quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines) to a list of game engines that might suit your needs.

Comment: I have seen this. The list seems outdated to some degree and most are 3d.

Comment: Oops sorry, didn't notice that they're most 3D.

Answer (score 0):

I truly do not know if such a engine/framework exists. I think you are going to have to sacrifice a platform or two.

PyGame will run on everything you mentioned besides iOS.
http://www.pygame.org/news.html

That would be where I would start.

Answer (score 0):

[V-Play](http://v-play.net) (I am part of the developer team) supports all your mentioned platforms from a single code base. A wide range of tutorials, examples, demos and full source code of some games that are already live in the App Stores will help you [get started](http://v-play.net/doc/) quickly.